# resolve a referenced mongoose document from a virtual attribute

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to work out how to resolve a related document so data can be loaded from an external file with no knowledge of the internal id from mongodb.

So I was thinking I could do something like this with virtual attributes where I use an alternate identifier to look up the value and replace the ObjectId:

```
InventorySchema.virtual('locationIdentifier')
  .set(function (identifier) {
    var inventory = this;

    Location.findOne({'identifier': identifier}, function(err, result){
      if (err || !result){
        this.location = undefined;
        return;
      }
      inventory.location = result._id;
    })
  });
```

But the setter is synchronous while the lookup is asynchronous. So I think that's why the value is not populated by time I need it. Is there a recommended way to "block the setter" until the async call is finished?

Comment: Setters and getters are sync so you can't use it this way. Have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-fill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same issues [Asynchronous Setters/Getters](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/517) and [Support for Asynchronous Virtual](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1894)  are talked in mongoose, and one solution to solve is to use `custom method`, sample codes as below.

```
InventorySchema.method('SetLocationIdentifier', function (identifier, cb) {
    var inventory = this;

    Location.findOne({'identifier': identifier}, function(err, result){
      if (err || !result){
        this.location = undefined;
        return cb();
      }
      inventory.location = result._id;
      cb();
    })
  });
```

Comment: Ok thanks I ended up just using a custom method.  It would have been nice to have it automatically set during the constructor logic, but that's okay, it works... cheers.